# How to display the Case Number as a url in lightning data table

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have created formula field name display eFile which creates a dynamic url for each eFile Number

```
HYPERLINK("https://abc-communityabc.cs93.force.com/cs/s/case/"+Id+"/detail",""+CaseNumber)
```

eFile.js

```
 handleFetchSelectFieldToDisplay(temp)
    {
this.isLoading = true;
this.columns = [];
this.selectedFields =[];
 fetch_Select_Fields_To_Display({
    ListViewId : temp
        }).then(data=>{
    if(data)
    {
        this.columns = this.emptyArray;
        console.log('lv name ----' + this.selectedItemValue + 'lv Id ----' + this.selecte+'---Columns = ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        this.columns = [];
       for(let key in data) 
       {
            if(key==='eFile Number')
            {
                this.columns.push({label: 'Case Number', fieldName: 'DisplayeFile__c', type: 'url',sortable: true,typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'CaseNumber'}}});
            }
            else{
            
                this.columns.push({label: key , fieldName: data[key],sortable:true,filterable:true});                                   
            }
            
    }
    for(let key in data)
    {
        this.selectedFields = Object.keys(data);


    }
    
    this.columns.push({type : 'action',
    typeAttributes :{
        rowActions : actions,
        menuAlignment : 'right'
    }});
console.log('Selected values - '+JSON.stringify(this.selectedFields));
this.handlefetcheFiles(temp);
    }
}).catch(error=>{
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error!!'+error.message,
            message: '',
            variant: 'error',
        }),
    );
})





 }
```

Apex code

```
       List<Case> cList = new List<Case>();
                 Query = 'Select DisplayeFile__c,Id,'+fieldsToDisplay+' From Case where ' + 
                    propertyIds+'  AND  '+filter ;
                   cList = Database.query(Query);
                   return cList;
```

[image: Not geting eFile Number field in blue color and the url is not getting correct]

Not getting eFile Number field in blue color and the url is not getting correct.

on click of eFile number getting below url in which unnecessary some extra code is concatenated

```
%3Ca%20href%3D%22https//abc-communityabc.cs93.force.com/cs/s/case/5004F00000AbruD/detail"%20target%3D"_blank">00565777</a>
```

for security purpose i had added abc instead of organization-name so

Comment: this.columns.push({label: 'Case Number', fieldName: 'DisplayeFile__c', type: 'url',sortable: true,typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'CaseNumber'}}}); add other attributes as well  like in target = values of formula field

Comment: can you tell me one example

Answer (score 0):

You need to have that column with type : url . Refer the playground with a working example
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/kPSqiPxWk/12/edit

Comment: I got the solution actually my formula is wrong i used these formula and now it is working correct LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))
+ 's/detail/' + Id
But now the case number is not in blue color so please tell me how to make  that field in blue color